# What is $\lim_{n\to\infty}P\left(\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^nU_i\in\left[-\frac{\varepsilon}{n^{2/3}},\frac{\varepsilon}{n^{2/3}}\right]\right)$?

Tags: probability, limits, probability-theory

I am having a rough time calculating this limit:

> Let $(U_i)_{i\ge 0}$ be an i.i.d. sequence of uniformly distributed random variables on $[-1,1]$. Let $\varepsilon>0$ be arbitrary. Find the limit $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \mathbb P\left(\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n U_i \in \left[-\frac{\varepsilon}{n^{2/3}},\frac{\varepsilon}{n^{2/3}}\right]\right)$$

So we are calculating the limit of the probability that this average of $U_i$ elements is within the interval specified. I am having a rough time just seeing how I combine the limit and the probability here. If somebody could show me this example, I am sure I can study that solution and try other problems myself, thanks in advance if anyone could help!

Comment: Are you allowed to use the central limit theorem?

Comment: Allowed to use anything, do you know a solution with that? :)

Comment: the interval should just be 0 with the limit of those fractions right? so does it become Phi(0) then?

Comment: Use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) instead of pictures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It follows almost immediately from CLT.  Specifically, $$\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n U_i \in \left[-\frac{\varepsilon}{n^{2/3}}, \frac{\varepsilon}{n^{2/3}}\right] \iff X_n := \sqrt{n}\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n U_i \in \left[-\frac{\varepsilon}{n^{1/6}}, \frac{\varepsilon}{n^{1/6}}\right]$$ and CLT implies $X_n$ converges in distribution to a continuous random variable $X$ (in fact, a Gaussian random variable, but this doesn't matter here).

Now note that $0 < m \leq n$ implies $$P\left(|X_n| \leq \varepsilon / n^{1/6}\right) \leq P\left(|X_n| \leq \varepsilon/m^{1/6}\right).$$
Therefore,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}P\left(|X_n| \leq \varepsilon / n^{1/6}\right) \leq \lim_{m\to\infty}\lim_{n\to\infty}P\left(|X_n| \leq \varepsilon/m^{1/6}\right) = \lim_{m\to\infty}P\left(|X| \leq \varepsilon/m^{1/6}\right) = 0$$

Comment: Thank you, the abstraction of the question totally made me forget the CLT and now I see this as a great example of how to use, thanks a lot for the calculation!